# Numpy doesn't add temporary variable to some element of vector

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Why can't i add temporal variable to x vector with numpy. I can do this using list , thanks for your answers

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[2],[2]])
h=10**-1
temp = x[0] + h
x[0] = temp
```

Comment: The array is integer dtype. 2.1 is saved as 2

Comment: Start with `x = np.array([[2.0],[2.0]])`.  Pay attention to the array `dtype`

Comment: thanks a lot. never thought that one :D